# For which $x$ does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For which $x$ does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=0$ ?

I just want to know if my solution correct. Here it is:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}+nx^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{nx^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{nx}=0\ \ \ \forall x
$$

Therefore, the answer is $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (I suggest that $x$ can't depend on $n$).

Am I correct?

Comment: You have to consider $x=0$ separately.

Comment: I don't see how you get the second in your chain of  four equalities.

Comment: Certainly, the limit equals $0$ in that case as well.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I thought I could get rid of the term, since it converges to zero.

Comment: @Bonrey you cannot evaluate the limiting behavior of only part of an expression.  This is not mathematically rigorous.

Comment: @Bonrey Think about when $x=0$; the second equality makes no sense then.

Comment: @heropup Could you show me please how I should have formally resolved this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would dispense with the entire calculation as it is and instead note that for $x > 0$, we can let $y = nx$, and as $n \to \infty$, $y \to \infty$.  Hence the limit in this case is equivalent to $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{1 + y^2} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{1}{y + 1/y} = 0.$$  When $x < 0$, then the same substitution has $y \to -\infty$, hence $$\lim_{y \to -\infty} \frac{y}{1 + y^2} = \lim_{y \to -\infty} \frac{1}{y+1/y} = 0.$$  Then the case $x = 0$ is trivial since $$\frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^2} = 0$$ identically.

To write $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1/n + n x^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n x^2}$$ isn't mathematically wrong so much as *sloppy reasoning*.  There are examples for which this does not work; e.g., $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1/n + 2/n + \cdots + n/n}$$ with your reasoning would suggest that since each term in the denominator tends to $0$ except the last, that the result would be $1$.  But it is not; the result is $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand everything.